# Como comparar arrays ignorando a ordem dos elementos no Jest?

Tags: javascript, array, jest

Em uma situação onde tenho dois *arrays*, é possível utilizar o [`expect`](https://jestjs.io/docs/expect) do Jest para uma comparação onde espero que os *arrays* sejam iguais, independente da ordem dos elementos?

Eu procurei, mas não encontrei nenhum método pronto para isso.

A comparação que utilizo atualmente é o [`.toEqual`](https://jestjs.io/docs/expect#toequalvalue), que funciona apenas se a ordem dos elementos do array forem a mesma:

```
const array = [{ name: 'Bob' }, { name: 'Alice' }];
expect(array).toEqual([{ name: 'Bob' }, { name: 'Alice' }]); // OK
expect(array).toEqual([{ name: 'Alice' }, { name: 'Bob' }]); // Erro
```

Comment: Há uma solução simples usando o pacote de expansão do Jest [jest-extended](https://github.com/jest-community/jest-extended). O uso desse pacote estaria dentro do escopo de sua pergunta?

Comment: Sim, @AugustoVasques, super válido.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Uma alternativa seria instalar o pacote [jest-extended](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jest-extended), cujo o objetivo é adicionar outros "matchers" aos já existentes, e usar o método [`expect.toIncludeSameMembers(\[members\])`](https://github.com/jest-community/jest-extended#toincludesamemembersmembers) que verifica se duas arrays contêm valores iguais, em qualquer ordem:

```javascript
test('passa quando as matrizes correspondem em uma ordem diferente', () => {
  expect([1, 2, 3]).toIncludeSameMembers([3, 1, 2]);
  expect([{ foo: 'bar' }, { baz: 'qux' }]).toIncludeSameMembers([{ baz: 'qux' }, { foo: 'bar' }]);
});
```

<sup>Nota: O exemplo acima faz parte da documentação do fabricante.</sup>

Resultando:

```
 PASS  ./sum.test.js
  ✓ passa quando as matrizes correspondem em uma ordem diferente (3 ms)

Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       1 passed, 1 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        1.131 s, estimated 2 s
Ran all test suites.
Done in 3.50s.
```

Answer (score 5):

#### Comparar os arrays já ordenados

A alternativa mais óbvia é utilizar o `sort` para fazer com que os arrays sejam comparados numa mesma ordem. Nesse caso, ordenemos pela propriedade `name`:

```
const sortByName = (os) => os.sort((a, b) => a.name.localeCompare(b.name));

const array = [{ name: 'Bob' }, { name: 'Alice' }];
const expected = [{ name: 'Alice' }, { name: 'Bob' }];

expect(sortByName(array)).toEqual(sortByName(expected)); // Ok
```

Nesse caso, a comparação é feita pensando em chaves como string, mas qualquer critério ordenação estável funcionaria.

#### Utilizar um contêiner no qual a ordem não é critério de comparação

Uma outra opção é converter o array em `Set`, onde a ordem não é um critério de comparação:

```
const array = [{ name: 'Bob' }, { name: 'Alice' }];
const expected = [{ name: 'Alice' }, { name: 'Bob' }];

expect(new Set(array)).toEqual(new Set(expected)); // Ok
```

O problema com isso é que o *set*, por não permitir elementos duplicados, consideraria iguais dois arrays com um diferente número de elementos iguais para o `Set`. Para corrigir isso, é necessário comparar também os arrays pelo seu comprimento.

```
const array = ['b', 'b', 'a'];
const expected = ['a', 'b'];

expect(new Set(array)).toEqual(new Set(expected)); // Ok
expect(array).toHaveLength(expected.length); // Falha justamente
```

#### `expect.arrayContaining`

Ou utilizar o método `arrayContaining`, tal como sugeriu a [outra resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/524725/69296), mas nesse caso, assim como fizemos no *set*, também terá que se atentar ao comprimento do array:

```
const array = ['b', 'b', 'a'];
const expected = ['a', 'b'];

expect(array).toEqual(expect.arrayContaining(expected)); // Ok
expect(array).toHaveLength(expected.length); // Falha justamente
```

Comment: Entre o `Set` e o *array*, a segunda opção me parece mais simples, já que não precisa da conversão. A ordenação é interessante, e como comentei na outra resposta, daria para criar um [*matcher* customizado](https://jestjs.io/docs/expect#custom-matchers-api), só ficaria mais complexo por precisar de mais argumentos (se for um objeto, precisaria indicar uma propriedade para ordenar).

Comment: Fui pesquisar o [código do `arrayContaining`](https://github.com/facebook/jest/blob/bc50e7f360ab1845abbaa0b3ad788caead0d3174/packages/expect/src/asymmetricMatchers.ts#L115) por curiosidade, para ver como ele fazia, e ele percorre os dois arrays (com `.every` e `.some`) para encontrar uma equivalência. Um pouquinho melhor que a ordenação, mas precisa do `.toHaveLength`, como você disse :)

Comment: Aos visitantes futuros: acabei de perceber um detalhe que não foi mencionado, se usar `toHaveLength` e `arrayContaining` para comparar `[1,2]` com `[1,1]`, não funcionará conforme o esperado (o teste passará, `[1,1]` tem o mesmo tamanho e está contido em `[1,2]`). Então, dentre as opções dessa resposta, ordenar ou utilizar o `Set` são melhores.

Answer (score 3):

Use uma combinação com o [`arrayContaining`](https://jestjs.io/pt-BR/docs/expect#expectarraycontainingarray) dentro do `toEqual`:

```
const array = [{ name: 'Bob' }, { name: 'Alice' }]

expect(array).toEqual(
  expect.arrayContaining([{ name: 'Alice' }, { name: 'Bob' }])
)
```

Ele ignoraria a ordem do array nesse caso.

Ou talvez tentar ordenar ambos os arrays antes de comparar com o `toEqual`.

### Alguns detalhes

Como descrito na documentação sobre `arrayContaining`:

> `expect.arrayContaining(array)` corresponde a um array recebido que contém todos os elementos no array esperado. Ou seja, o array esperado é um **subconjunto** do array recebido. Portanto, combina com um array recebido que contém elementos que não estão no array esperado.

"*Ou seja, o array esperado é um **subconjunto** do array recebido*" - Isto implica dizer que basta que o array esperado tenha determinados valores do array testado para o teste passar. Esse comportamento é semelhante ao `expect.objectContaining` onde não precisa que todas as chaves estejam presentes no objeto, apenas algumas verificadas no teste já são o suficiente para passar. Mas e para o caso onde o array seja o mesmo, ou seja, mesmo tamanho, mas desordenado? Um teste como o abaixo passaria sem problemas:

```
it.only('array test', () => {
  const array = [{ name: 'Bob' }, { name: 'Alice' }, { name: 'Foo' }]

  expect(array).toEqual(
    expect.arrayContaining([{ name: 'Alice' }, { name: 'Bob' }])
  )
})
```

Repare que

- `[{ name: 'Alice' }, { name: 'Bob' }]`

é um subconjunto de

- `[{ name: 'Bob' }, { name: 'Alice' }, { name: 'Foo' }]`

Este teste deveria falhar pois estaria faltando `{ name: 'Foo' }` no `expect.arrayContaining`.

### Como resolver

Do modo mais imperativo e simples, comparar o tamanho dos arrays usando `toHaveLength()` antes de verificar com o `expect.arrayContaining`:

```
// funcao utilitária para reuso em todos os testes
function checkArraysInAnyOrder (array: any[], expected: any[]) {
  expect(array).toHaveLength(expected.length)
  expect(array).toEqual(expect.arrayContaining(expected))
}
```

Sucesso:

```
it('array test', () => {
  const array = [{ name: 'Bob' }, { name: 'Alice' }]
  const expected = [{ name: 'Alice' }, { name: 'Bob' }]

  checkArraysInAnyOrder(array, expected) // sucesso
})
```

Falha:

```
it('array test', () => {
  const array = [{ name: 'Bob' }, { name: 'Alice' }, { name: 'Foo' }]
  const expected = [{ name: 'Alice' }, { name: 'Bob' }]

  checkArraysInAnyOrder(array, expected) // falha
})
```

---

Como discutido nos comentários, `checkArraysInAnyOrder` poderia ser um *matcher customizado*, mas creio que o esforço e complexidade não valeria a pena. Usar bibliotecas da comunidade que estendem os recursos do Jest como [jest-extended](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jest-extended#toincludesamemembersmembers), poderiam ajudar a chegar no objetivo. Esta, inclusive, possui o método [`toIncludeSameMembers`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jest-extended#toincludesamemembersmembers) que poderia ser usado para cumprir o objetivo:

> Use `.toIncludeSameMembers` when checking if two arrays contain equal values, in any order.
>
> ```
> test('passes when arrays match in a different order', () => {
>   expect([1, 2, 3]).toIncludeSameMembers([3, 1, 2]);
>   expect([{ foo: 'bar' }, { baz: 'qux' }]).toIncludeSameMembers([{ baz: 'qux' }, { foo: 'bar' }]);
> });
> ```

Claro que cabe a discussão e análise se vale a pena adicionar um biblioteca inteira apenas para uso de uma funcionalidade específica. Ainda falando sobre essa biblioteca, você poderia se basear, ou copiar, o [código fonte](https://github.com/jest-community/jest-extended/tree/main/src/matchers/toIncludeSameMembers) que implementa o `toIncludeSameMembers` e criar seu próprio *match*.

Comment: É de fato uma opção bem interessante, consigo pensar em criar um [*matcher* customizado](https://jestjs.io/docs/expect#custom-matchers-api) para isso, porém verificando a `length` do array, como disse o Luiz Felipe. Acho importante você mencionar este detalhe sobre o tamanho na sua resposta, já que `expect([1,2,3]).toEqual(expect.arrayContaining([3, 2]));` funcionaria (mesmo sem ter o `1`).

Comment: @RafaelTavares bem observado.  Mais tarde vou fazer uns ajustes na resposta também :)

Comment: Aos visitantes futuros: acabei de perceber mais um detalhe que não foi mencionado, se usar `toHaveLength` e `arrayContaining` para comparar `[1,2]` com `[1,1]`, não funcionará conforme o esperado (o teste passará, `[1,1]` tem o mesmo tamanho e está contido em `[1,2]`).